# Why first item of awt choice in java not being selected?

Tags: java

I am developing Automated tests on Selenium Java and following is the configuration of my laptop.

Operating System:Windows 7 Ultimate.

Java Version:[Java Version details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSSBV.png)
Eclipse Version:[Eclipse IDE details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ytqD.png)

I am facing a problem with awt Choice component in java, as 
when I open the choice drop down and click on 1st item, then it is not selected
then i select any other item from the list, and that item selected, 
now when I select the first item again it is being selected.
Why it is not being selected on first click.

```
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Frame;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.Label;

import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.MenuBar;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.Image;

public class MainMenu1 extends Frame implements ItemListener{
    Choice bl;
    String[][] userselect = new String[5][4];

    MainMenu1() {
        setTitle("Automation Test");
        setLayout(null);setBackground(Color.pink);setSize(800,400); setLocation(200,200);setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);

        bl = new Choice();bl.add("IE");bl.add("Chrome");bl.add("FireFox");bl.add("Safari");bl.add("Opera");bl.setSize(90, 21);bl.setLocation(180, 90);
        add(bl); 

        bl.addItemListener(this);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }       
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent i){
        if(i.getSource()==bl)
        {
            System.out.println(bl.getSelectedItem());
            userselect[0][1]=bl.getSelectedItem();
        }
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MainMenu1();
    }
}
```

Comment: And it HAS to be done AWT? (which was replaced by Swing nearly 18 years, which was replaced by JavaFX in recent years)

Comment: I'm not seeing your particular problem, but I would suggest adding in a "blank" item as the first selected item to remove the confusion